# Numerical Integration recognized as a variable, not a function

Tags: matlab, function, variables, integral

I'm trying to perform a numerical integral in MatLab.  However, I messed up and assigned `integral` as a variable instead of using it as a function.  Now, when I try to use it as a function, like

```
answer = integral(fun,x0,x1)
```

I get an error message saying

> "At compilation, 'integral' was determined to be a
>   variable and this variable is uninitialized."

This seems like such a silly question, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to clear integral from being a variable, and go back to being used as a function!

I have tried `clearvars`, saving the script without the variable `integral`, and even closing down MatLab and trying again.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: do you name a variable integral somewhere else? Try clear all and clc

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot: Why `clc`?

Comment: @RobertP. Couldn't remember which was clear workspace

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot clc just clear the command window, clear all is what you want

Comment: What do you get if you type `help integral` or `whos integral`? Clearing the workspace _should_ work.

Comment: Are you using Matlab coder to compile? If so the `integral` function isn't in the [supported function list](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html), hence at compilation it looks like a variable which hasn't been initialised.